# What is _transient_random_seed for?

Tags: wpdb, options

This is a very short question. `_transient_random_seed` is in `wp_options`.

What is it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wp_rand function mixes up the randomization of random numbers with various means, and in between runs it stores the random seed so as to keep the shuffling going every run. The random_seed transient is where it stores that.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the login session?

Comment: No, WordPress doesn't use "sessions". Currently, the only place I see wp_rand() being used is in wp_generate_password(), which generates randomized passwords for new accounts.

Comment: WordPress does have sessions since 4.0 https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-includes/session.php/ - Thanks

Comment: Those aren't "sessions" in the common parlance of "PHP sessions". They probably should have picked a better name. Basically, that code was introduced to have logout affect all cookies for a user. The session tokens there do use the generate password function, so yes, wp_rand affects them.